# Number of zeroes of an analytic function inside unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in $\{z: \ |z|\leq 1\}$ such that $|f(z)-z|<|z|$ on $\{z: \ |z|=1\}$. Find the number of zeroes of $f(z)$ in $\{z: \ |z|<1\}$.

My first thought was to use Rouche's theorem inside the unit disk but the problem is to construct such $f(z)$ that satisfies the given condition. Kindly help me to construct $f(z)$ or is there any other easy approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to construct $f$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $h(z) =f(z)- z,$ $g(z)=z$ then $|h(z)|<|g(z) |$ on the unit circle hence the functions $h(z) +g(z) = f(z) $ and  $g(z) =z$ have the same number of zeros inside the circle by Rouche Theorem. So the answer is $1.$

Comment: thanks..great MotylaNogaTomkaMazura's

Answer (score 0):

Note: $|f(z)-z|<|z|\leq |z|+|f(z)|$. By Rouche's Theorem, $f$ has same number of zeros with $z$ on $B(0,1)$. Hence, it has 1 zero on $B(0,1)$.